# MySQL CREATE TABLE & FOREIGN KEY Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm not a DB guy, but I've been hacking away at this one for a bit and can't seem to nail the issue. I've read the relevant doc page (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and I can't see where my syntax may be an issue.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 84: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE C' at line 5
```

This is the relevant SQL - order(id) and user(id) are auto incrementing int(10) fields in their respective tables.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_orders`;
CREATE TABLE `user_orders` (
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_orders_user_id`, `user_orders_order_id`)
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order(id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) AUTO_INCREMENT=50;
```

Help would be appreciated - especially if you can explain what I've missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a comma after your PK:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`user_orders_user_id`, `user_orders_order_id`), -- <-------
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id) ...
```

And you'll want to use the InnoDB engine if you want your foreign keys enforced:

```
) AUTO_INCREMENT=50 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have no idea what you're doing. Your code is full of errors.

`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_orders_user_id`, `user_orders_order_id`)

Where do the `user_orders_user_id` come from. And why double.
Take the time to read your code. It should be 
, PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `order_id`)

FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order(id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) AUTO_INCREMENT=50;

I suggest you take a different approach. 
First re-order your commas, so you can easily switch them.
Then Place # in front of your FK lines.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_orders`;
CREATE TABLE `user_orders` 
( user_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
, order_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
, PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `order_id`)
#, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES userS(id)  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
# , FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
# AUTO_INCREMENT=50 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;
```

Simplify.
This runs at least.
Then uncomment 1 line at a time.

Type

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

whenever you get weird mysql errors. Look for

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
160323 10:25:43 Error in foreign key constraint of table DEMO/user_orders:
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES userS(id)  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

This leads to the following solution.

```
    CREATE TABLE `USERS` 
( `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, `NAME` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, `EMAIL` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
, `ACTIVE` BOOLEAN NOT NULL default 0
, CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
, UNIQUE KEY `UK_ID` (`ID`) USING BTREE
, UNIQUE KEY `UK_NAME` (`NAME`)
, UNIQUE KEY `UK_EMAIL` (`EMAIL`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_orders`;
CREATE TABLE `user_orders` 
( user_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL # default '0'
, order_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL # default '0'
, PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `order_id`)
, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USERS(id)  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
# , FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order_id ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
# AUTO_INCREMENT=50 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;
```